# how to insert values separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql

how to insert values into database with comma.
in my quiz app 4 multiple choices. user can take quiz can click next button each time post values something like this:

```
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
$AnswerID = $_POST['AnswerID'];
$questionid = $_POST['questionid'];
$timetaken = $_POST['timetaken'];
```

each time user can take 10 questions for quiz. how to save these values into following:

```
    user_id category_id answer_id  questionid  timetaken 
        1         2     3,4,4,3    1,2,3,4      2,3,4,5<br>
```

category_id same for 10 questions.
how to save only answer_id,  questionid , timetaken values separated by comma?

Comment: Are you aware of MySql datatypes? Use string format to insert comma separated values. Or just use different rows for every record of question-answer.

Comment: Use appropriate data types

Answer (score 1):

First use dtat type for your column as VARCHAR or Text

And in your code you have array values for answer_id, question_id and timetaken.

I mean you must set attr name for input tag something like `name="answer_id[]"`.

It will help you lot

and then in your php code before your insert query just use a impode function with comma delimator

Something like below:

```
$ansres = implode(",",$_POST['answer_id']);
```

and then use this variable in your insert query.

It will insert value as you required.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes. It will help. `:)`  `:D`

Comment: Pls show me full code.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have an array to store the multiple answer and do [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$yourAnswer=implode(',',$yourFinalArray);
```

Comment: @Naveen Golla any updates ? up-vote and accept the answer if helped thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save only answer_id, question_id and time_taken in only ONE column in your database table, here's the solution:

Create a TEXT column in your DB table, where you will save results in this example i will call this colum "scores" and the table will be game_stuffs

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "dbpasswd";
$dbname = "Data_base_name";


$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
$AnswerID = $_POST['AnswerID'];
$questionid = $_POST['questionid'];
$timetaken = $_POST['timetaken'];
$RESULT = $AnswerID.",".$questionid.",".$timetaken;

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "INSERT INTO game_stuffs (scores) VALUES ('$RESULT')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Score successfully saved to database";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Pls give me full code

Comment: I want separate columns like this:'user_id,cat_id,q_id,ans_id,time_taken'

Comment: The question we may ask to you is:
How do you want to store the data in database ? Do you want them in only one column, all together separated by a comma, or each value in his dedicated column ?

Comment: In category_id is same for 10 questions.when click next button each time change only question_id,answer_id,time_taken.

Comment: Sorry but this is unclear to me

Comment: Yes i want to each value in his dedicated column

Answer (score 0):

Data type of your columns(answer_id, questionid, timetaken) must be text.

Use Array to store multiple answer and implode them and save.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your columns with different values as VARCHAR in the MySQL database and insert them as Strings with a comma as separator.